# libRInside.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: r, distributed, rinside

I installed distributed R sucessfully in Redhat linux 6.5. I am getting " libRInside.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" exception while trying to launch distributed R library?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Now:

- What R version did you install, and how?
- Did you install RInside as well?  It is an add-on package
- It depends on Rcpp too

When you have all your ducks in a row, it is as simple as just saying `make` in one of the eight (!!) example subdirectories.  In `standard` we have over a dozen examples alone.

To create just one:

```
edd@max:~/git/rinside/inst/examples/standard(master)$ make rinside_sample0
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include \
  -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include \
  -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/include \
  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security \
  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -pedantic -Wall \  
  rinside_sample0.cpp  -Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp  \
  -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -lrt -ldl -lm  \
  -lblas -llapack  -L/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/lib -lRInside \
  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/lib -o rinside_sample0
edd@max:~/git/rinside/inst/examples/standard(master)$ ./rinside_sample0 
Hello, world!
edd@max:~/git/rinside/inst/examples/standard(master)$
```

The paths are specific to my Debian/Ubuntu system (and I added some linebreaks here for exposition) but this will work on any other sane system.

Comment: Hi could you tell what is solution of the problem. I do not get what your example does

Comment: It shows how an example of the package in question compiles and links against a shared library, the issue of the OP and then runs, printing 'Hello, world!' as simple examples do.  So it is an existence-proof of the package working here.